# Automagically instanciate property but retain is Nothing capability

Tags: .net, vb.net

In vb.net I try to have a class with a Dictionary property that can be Nothing but also can access the members.

Something like:

```
Dim configClass = new ConfigurationClass()

If configClass.DictProperty is Nothing Then doNothingSomewhere(configClass.DictProperty)

configClass.DictProperty.Add("key", "value")
If configClass.DictProperty.Count > 0 then SetListSomewhere(configClass.DictProperty)

configClass.DictProperty.Clear()
If configClass.DictProperty.Count = 0 then EmptyListSomewhere(configClass.DictProperty)
```

In the real case the configClass is passed around the checks are done somewhere else.
Note that I want to avoid that the user needs to do an explicit `configClass.DictPropery = new Dictionary(of String, String)`. They should be able to as well as an explicit Nothing assigment, but they should not need to.

Or otherway around: Is there a way to check in the properties Getter if access is for the value itself or to a member/property of the object somehow?

Comment: There might be other alternatives, but one that is guaranteed to work is to wrap the dictionary in your own object type.  If you want it to be non-nullable, it will have to be a `Structure`; note that these can have surprising behaviors at times, but I wouldn't expect anything interesting to happen when it mainly just contains a reference type.